# Remove specific characters from date string

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string

```
INSTALLDATE=Tue Nov 07 19:35:38 UTC 2017
```

from which I want to extract the timestamp in this format

```
Tue Nov 07 19:35:38 2017
```

i.e. with the timezone removed.

What is the correct regex for it?

I am able to remove `INSTALLDATE` but I am not sure how to match `UTC` and remove it from my matched string.

My current regex :

```
($string) = ($string =~ /INSTALLDATE=(.*)/);
```

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.  You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47419301/edit) to include more information.  What have you tried so far?  Which regex are you using to grab the `INSTALLDATE` part?  Thanks!

Comment: Please show the code that you do have

Comment: Is it always UTC, or do you need to handle non-UTC timezones?

Comment: thank you for help. this is my current regex : 
($string) = ($string =~ /INSTALLDATE=(.*)/); 
I am not sure how to remove UTC from it.

Comment: it's always UTC, that's for sure.

Comment: Was thinking in terms of parse the TZ, but my first pass with `Time::Piece` doesn't like it.

Comment: oh I am not able to use any of these libraries :
 use Date::Parse;
use DateTime
use Time::Piece

Comment: Btw, why couldn't you use `Time::Piece`? It's core. (You'd have to parse the string here in some other way first, anyway.)

Comment: `s/UTC\s//`, anyone? Does it have to be a single line of code? Sometimes more verbose is better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The year is a useful marker since it can't show anywhere else

```
$string =~ s/INSTALLDATE=(.*?)\s\w+(\s[0-9]{4})/$1$2/;
```

The `.*?` matches non-greedily up to the last word before the four-digit pattern.

Detail

- The `?` quantifier after `.*` makes it match until the *first* occurrence of the pattern that follows. Without `?` it would match as far as it can, globbing up everything in between
- That next pattern is: space—word (`\w+`)—space—4 digits (`[0-9]{4}`); end of timestamp
- It replaces the whole pattern with what has been captured in `()`s, first in `$1` second in `$2`

Comment: could you please explain the regex?

Comment: @PushpinderSingh Added notes, please let me know if it isn't good enough

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It works! I can't upvote because of the low reputation for now.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer a positional approach

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

my $s = 'INSTALLDATE=Tue Nov 07 19:35:38 UTC 2017';

my $date = join ' ', ( $s =~ /[\w:]+/g )[1,2,3,4,6];

say $date;
```

#### output

```
Tue Nov 07 19:35:38 2017
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Another way

Partly inspired by @zdim, you can do:

```
$string =~ s/^.*?=(.*?)UTC\s*(.*)$/\1\2/
```

This matches everything up to the first `=` (`^.*?=`), saves everything after the `=` and before `UTC` into `\1` (`(.*?)`), skips the `UTC` and any following whitespace (`UTC\s*`), and saves the rest of the line into `\2` (`(.*)$`).  Then it replaces the string with `\1\2`, i.e., the first and second saved parts stuck together.  The result is that everything from the beginning through the first `=` is gone, and `UTC` followed by any space is also gone.  Example:

```
$ echo "INSTALLDATE=Tue Nov 07 19:35:38 UTC 2017" |  
    perl -ne 's/^.*?=(.*?)UTC\s*(.*)$/\1\2/; print;'
Tue Nov 07 19:35:38 2017
```

#### Original answer

I only know a two-step for this, although there's probably a one-liner.  I used:

```
echo "INSTALLDATE=Tue Nov 07 19:35:38 UTC 2017" | 
  perl -ne 'if(/=(.*)$/) { my $rest = $1; $rest =~ s/UTC\s+//; print $rest;}'
```

and got `Tue Nov 07 19:35:38 2017`.

That is:

```
if(/=(.*)$/) {            # Grab everything after the = into $1
    my $rest = $1;        # copy $1 to writeable variable $rest
    $rest =~ s/UTC\s+//;  # Remove "UTC" and any following whitespace from $rest
    print $rest;          # Output to the console (you could do something else instead)
}
```

Comment: I don't know why someone downvoted this. It works fine. Thanks.

Comment: @PushpinderSingh Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 0):

The regex must contain 2 capturing groups:

- Between `=` and `UTC`.
- Between `UTC` and the end of the string.

So the regex can be as follows:

```
/=(.*) UTC (.*)$/
```

An elegant way to capture both groups is:

```
my @res = $txt =~ /=(.*) UTC (.*)$/;
```

Where `res` is an array catching all groups contained in the regex.

Then you can e.g. print both capturing groups, separated with a space:

```
print "Result: $res[0] $res[1]\n";
```

So the whole script can be as follows:

```
my $txt = "INSTALLDATE=Tue Nov 07 19:35:38 UTC 2017";
print "Source: $txt\n";
my @res = $txt =~ /=(.*) UTC (.*)$/;
print "Result: $res[0] $res[1]\n";
```